# Codemagic failed to publish Error: code -22020

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, codemagic

My build failed using Codemagic with the Error code -22020 after building the whole app.

```
 Successfully created archive at build/ios/xcarchive/Runner_4myti30z.xcarchive
Export build/ios/xcarchive/Runner_4myti30z.xcarchive to build/ios/ipa
Execute "xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath build/ios/xcarchive/Runner_4myti30z.xcarchive -exportPath build/ios/ipa -exportOptionsPlist /Users/builder/export_options.plist COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO"


▸ Export Succeeded

Successfully exported ipa to build/ios/ipa/Runner.ipa
Raw xcodebuild logs stored in /tmp/xcodebuild_logs/Runner_x1541cb8.log
```

Then in the publish part it drops me an error at the end

```
== Gathering artifacts ==


== Publishing artifacts ==

[skipped]

Publishing Runner.ipa to App Store Connect

/usr/bin/xcrun altool --validate-app -f /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/ipa/Runner.ipa -t ios -u *********@hotmail.com -p @env:APP_STORE_CONNECT_PASSWORD --output-format normal

    2020-09-01 08:48:58.794 altool[31554:179398] *** Error: Unable to validate archive '/Users/builder/clone/build/ios/ipa/Runner.ipa'.
    2020-09-01 08:48:58.794 altool[31554:179398] *** Error: code -22020 (Unable to validate your application. We are unable to create an authentication session.)



Failed to publish to App Store Connect


Build failed :|


Publishing failed :|
Failed to publish to App Store Connect
```

Answer (score 3):

The most common reason for the occurrence of this error message is using Apple ID password instead of [app-specific password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204397) in App Store Connect publishing settings.

To generate an app-specific password, sign in to your [Apple ID account page](https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage), navigate to the **Security** section and click **Generate Password…** below **App-Specific Passwords**. The generated app-specific password will be in this format: `abcd-efgh-ijkl-mnop`. Insert this value into the Codemagic UI or as a password in `codemagic.yaml` when setting up publishing to App Store Connect.

Note that the password should be generated with the same Apple account that you are using for publishing.

Comment: This was it! Microsoft OneNote had corrupted the password because I cut-and-pasted it from the Apple site and it came with some strange encoding. If you paste to a command line, then re-cut-and-paste into OneNote, you get rid of the strange encoding.

Comment: Where in Codemagic UI should the app-specific password be set?

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the upload error reason by downloading the generated ipa file from Code Magic and manually uploading it to AppStoreConnect with [Transporter application](https://apps.apple.com/br/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12).

Once Transporter shows you each error, fix them and try to upload again either with Transporter or CodeMagic. It should work if the errors are fixed.